# ExecutorService where to store

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I need an executor service to invoke a 3rd party service, to save from rtt and latency, planning to fire all the 3rd party request concurrently.

I would like to know if I should create an ExecutorService per request ? or store at thread local? or one per application?

What happens if i never call `shutdown` explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you want to have a single `ExecutorService` per whole application. It's actually a thread pool in disguise, so you probably don't need a thread pool per one request or per thread.

Calling `shutdown()` is not necessary, but if this runs within a web application that you plan to redeploy, it will lead to memory leak.

Comment: memory leak? this is java man. application shutdown should shutdown the executor service than i guess.

Comment: Calling `shutdown` *is* necessary if you don't explicitly call `System.exit` and depend on things like all your non-daemon threads terminating, like disposing all your Swing windows to close a Swing application. Still, +1

Comment: @DarthVader He meant when redeploying a web app, like a servlet running in JBoss or Tomcat.